# Was this where Rex and Ahsoka parted ways?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

At the end of season 7:

> Ahsoka and Rex crash their ship, they bury all of the clones.

We know, from the Ahsoka novel, and Rebels, that at some point Ahsoka and Rex parted ways for their own safety.  For a while, I fully believed that this moment at the end of the show wasn't that moment.  They've both just lost so much.

Why would they leave one another so soon?  Does anything point towards this moment being where they did so?

Comment: The relationship didn't work out.. Why does this have to be complex?

Comment: What do you mean?  I'm not talking about them ever having any sort of romantic relationship.  I just mean that they were very close and eventually, as we saw in Rebels, went their separate ways - so when did that happen?

Comment: You might see it from the point of view that if they split up they would be harder to hunt down, if there was ever any suspicion, from the Empire, that Rex and Asoka might have survived. You also have to see it that they were two distinct individuals that would struggle to blend into the general population, better yet together- a former-Jedi and  a Clone Deserter/rebel